# EF6 Query Precompilation

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to precompile the EF query, so that the app has no need to compile it (even if it is executed for the first time)?

I have lots of complex queries which, when using L2E take some time to execute. For example, for one query that I benchmarked Sql Server profiler reports approx 300ms execution time, but actually this query is completed after approx 4.5s on my PC (Xeon Quad Core 2.6 GHz with 8GBs of RAM. This means that my PC is waiting for data to arrive approx 0.5s, and spends approx 4s to compile and execute query, and finally read the data on my PCs (which is 4 records only). Thats a lot of time, especially since ToListAsyns() will not return control to the UI until the actual query is sent to database, so that means that all 4 seconds my app "hangs". One way around this is to use Task.Run() instead of ToListAsync, but that will only allow my application to show some waiting sign, there will still be a 4s delay.

On some older PCs this could mean that user will be waiting for 10s for query compilation, which is not something that is desirable. So, anyone knows how can I precompile all my queries, so that even the first time they are executed without delay?

Comment: The Entity Framework June 2011 CTP supports a new feature called Auto-Compiled LINQ Queries.  Now every LINQ to Entities query that you execute automatically gets compiled and placed in EF’s query cache.   Each additional time you run the query, EF will find it in its query cache and won’t have to go through the whole compilation process again.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/30/auto-compiled-linq-queries-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

It won't work if u have disabled the query cache

Comment: @Legends This is not truly a solution for two reasons: 1) in a desktop app some queries could be executed only once in a day - that means query will actually never be compiled, and 2) most of my queries contain Enumerable.Contains in where query. This works OK when executing a SP, where you can make use of TVP (supported in EF), but when using L2E then each time you execute a query, a new one will be generated, so there is no auto query compilation.

Comment: I am not an EF Geek, but as a work around I would suggest, that you precompile all queries asynchronously at application start,, for example you have 30 queries, but ordered in that way, that the most frequently used ones get compiled at first and the less frequent ones compiled later in the compile execution pipe. Where is the db on the client or on a server? If it is one the serverside, discard LTE and use pure T-SQL, so that the execution plan will be cached in the db. Perhaps this will also work if the db is on the clientside, but cannot confirm that.

Comment: The point is that they cannot be compiled when having Enumerable.Contains(...) in L2E queries, which I have just found out while reading about the topic. And as I have said in my previous comment TVP works correctly with SP in EF6, but the client decision was not to use SPs for the sake of maintainability.

Comment: I have the same problem: Using EF6, my query called multiple times is not precompiled and takes ages to do it. The query is long and complex and I only call it sending a different input parameter every time I call it (string). I've tried everything but still does not work (I dont have calls to Enumerable.Contains(...) which is the only limitation. Any idea why? So desperated with this, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the concept you're looking for is 'Pre-Generated Mapping Views' — https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx

While searching for that feature I also came across this fairly recent relevant article — http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2014/07/09/three-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-first-query-performance/

Note that in EF 5 support was added to automatically compile LINE-to-Entities queries so the compilation no longer occurred every time — https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#4

Comment: No, this is not what I am talking about, views will be generated on first query execution, which is normally on application startup. I am talking about precompiling a complex query, so that EF6 does not need to generate one everytime it executes L2E query. And based of what I have read so far, in case where you have complex L2E query that have something like: where Enumerable.Contains(x.Id), with current version of EF6 it is not possible to achieve this, and you will most definetely suffer the compilation performance each time you execute a query,

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the separate topic of compiling LINQ-to-Entities queries.

Comment: You're correct that queries using `IEnumerable<T>.Contains<T>(T value)` cannot be cached. Although the last article points out that query performance was improved in EF 6.

Comment: I already know about the auto compile feature in EF6, and I have already discussed that with @Legend in the question comments. That does not help me with the issue I am describing.

Comment: I feel my answer is valid. Pre-generating the mapping views will cause that step to be skipped on the first query execution. From your question that seems to be what you're seeking.

Comment: Where did you see that in the question? Read the last sentence, where it clearly says that I would like to run each query as it is precompiled, even for the first time. Even if I cache the views, the problem would still exist.

Comment: @MattBrooks Pre-generated mapping views are not the same as compiled queries. Even if you pre-generate your mapping views, EF still needs to compile your queries.